# Railsで日付文字列をunixtimeで保存する

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Railsで
"2017-3-6"などのデータをunixtimeで保存する場合、どこで処理を持つのが一般的でしょうか？

```
def set_params
  tmp = params.require(:user).permit(
    :name,
    :date
  )
  tmp[:date] = DateTime.parse(tmp[:date]).to_i unless tmp[:date].blank? 
  return tmp
end
```

現状上記のようにして、set_paramsを

```
User.assign_attributes set_params
```

のようにしているのですが、何か良い方法ありましたらご教示頂けますと幸いです。

Answer (score 0):

Rails は、その永続層には何かしらの RDB を用いる設計です。

RDB では、大概 TIMESTAMP のデータ型が取り扱えます。これは、 unixtime でデータの日付を保管することに相当します。 (プラス、もろもろの日付として取り扱うための各種関数などが使えて、便利です。)

なので、普通は、「UNIX TIME を保存する」ことはあまりないのですが、何か、これをやらなければならない事情などありますでしょうか? (自分が想像できていないだけかもしれません)

もしそうであるならば、質問にを「編集」し、何故 Unix time を保存する必要が出てきたのかを、追記いただけますでしょうか。